# Finding a basis of p2 that contains my subset

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

> Write down a basis $B$ for $\mathbb{P}_2$ that contains $W = \left\{x^2+x, 1\right\}$ as a subset.

I was able to find $W$ from other parts of the assignment, but not sure how to do this.

Comment: What's the dimension of $P_2$?  What's the dimension of the span of $W$?  Can you identify any element of $P_2$ that's not in $W$?

Comment: Again the question on $p_2$, see the [old one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511676/finding-a-basis-of-p2). Can you use the answer given there?

Comment: Is the dimension of p2=3? I’m new to this I don’t have the best idea

Comment: @Ellie: The dimension of $P_2$ is the size of any basis for it.  If you know one basis, you know all the bases have the same (finite) size.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm writing an answer.

Yes the dimension of $\mathbb{P}_2$ is $3$. A basis of $\mathbb{P}_2$ is given by $\beta_1=\{1,x,x^2\}$. You want to complete $\beta_2=\{1,x^2+x\}$ into a basis of $\mathbb{P}_2$. But you can do this by just adding one element so that the elements in $\beta_1$ can be generated by the elements of $\beta_2$.

You can $x$, that is  consider $\beta=\{1,x,x^2+x\}$. Then $\beta $ is a basis of $\mathbb{P}_3$, as it contains $3$ elements and

$$1=1,\;x=x,x^2=(x^2+x)-x$$

Comment: Thank you I actually have it as ($x^2$+$x/2$,1) so for this could a basis of P2 be ($x^2$+$x/2$,x,1)

Comment: @Ellie yes it's still a basis.

Comment: Fab am to justify why it’s a basis of p2 would I say because it’s linearly independent and spans